# Search multiple directories with KFind or exclude specific path

Tags: find, kde

Is it possible to search multiple directories with KFind or to exclude a specific path?  Via CLI it is easy to do so with `find` e.g.

```
find DIR1 DIR2 DIR3 -iname "*.txt"
```

and

```
find DIR -path IGNOREPATH -prune -o -print
```

However, I would like to do it with the graphical tool.

Thanks for your suggestions!